# Openssl still pointing to LibreSSL 2.8.3

Tags: macos, openssl

In my mac version 10.15.5, openssl is still pointing to LibreSSL 2.8.3. I have used the below commands, but no luck

```
homebrew install libressl
```

After installation when I ran the version command it is still showing LibreSSL 2.8.3
Also below command is throwing error -

```
brew link --force openssl                                                
Warning: Refusing to link macOS provided/shadowed software: openssl@1.1
If you need to have openssl@1.1 first in your PATH run:
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openssl@1.1 you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include"
```

Answer (score 25):

You may already have this working.  To test run:
`which openssl`

Further, running this will advise which version is the default:
`openssl version`

To change to the homebrew version you need to add it into the path before the default.  To do this, edit the startup script for your shell (which it seems in your case is zsh).  So in your case edit `~/.zshrc` with your favorite text editor or something like:
`nano ~/.zshrc`

(for the default bash shell, use `nano ~/.bashrc`)

Insert a command to add the path to the brew installed OpenSSL using this line, preferably somewhere near the top of the file:

`export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"`

(At the time of writing the most recent version of OpenSSL has moved onto 1.1.1, so it may need to look like this now `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1.1/bin:$PATH"`)

Then "reload" the zsh startup script with this command:

`source ~/.zshrc`

You should now be seeing openssl 1.1 (no longer libressl) when running
`which openssl` or `openssl version`

Comment: This works properly - `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"`, which correctly returns latest `1.1.1i` (at time of comment) on `openssl version`

Comment: On my mac `/usr/local/opt/openssl` is a symlink to `../Cellar/openssl@1.1/1.1.1j` so in order to automatically point to an updated version of `openssl` it's better to `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"`

Answer (score 14):

For users with Apple M1 silicon OpenSSL installed by brew has a different location. You should add a line `export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"` at `~/.zshrc` file

Answer (score 4):

So for me, `openssl version` used to be `LibreSSL 2.8.3`. Doing `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"` only got it to *show* `OpenSSL 1.1.1i` in the terminal, and also `which openssl` gives me the right command, but it still doesn't work.

**So then adding the line `export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"` inside `~/.profile` worked.**

Not `~/.bash_profile` if you are using bash, or `~/.zshrc`, or `/etc/paths`.